# Master does not appear to be a git repository error

Tags: git

I've inherited a position and instructions for creating a new git repository. Unfortunately I've run into problems and no one here knows what to do. Hoping someone can help me out.

Here are the instructions I was left:

**Create a new repository:**

1. For these steps you need to be in the gitosis-admin repository, if you don't have it, in a suitable parent folder do: git clone git@xxx.xxx.x.xx:gitosis-admin.git
2. Edit gitosis.conf file - in gitosis-admin root, under [group base-repo] section, add the name of the new repo to the end of the "writable =" section.
3. Commit change and push back to gitosis-admin master.
4. For the next commands, my_new_project represents the name of your project
5. mkdir my_new_project
6. cd my_new_project
7. git init
8. Copy in any files you want to use to start the repo
9. git commit -a -m "Initializing new repository"
10. git remote add origin git@192.168.4.20:my_new_project.git
11. git push master
12. git push master:qa

So I did 1 and 2, with no problem. It created a local folder on my machine called gitosis-admin. I edited the gitosis.conf file as indicated. But when I try to do step 3 (which I assume is git push gitosis-admin master) bash tells me that

> fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this out, this may solve your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318918/fatal-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository

Comment: Eh. Now I get a different error. Tried `git remote add origin git@xxx.xxx.x.xx:loyalty.git` (my new project name) and it tells me `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"origin" is only the local NAME of the remote repository, it is not part of the command.

For example, you can write anything like:

```
git remote add fakeorigin git@xxx.xxx.x.xx:loyalty.git
```

To delete a remote repo, type:

```
git remote rm origin
```

Reference:
http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html